# Input fields are outside the form field when in bootstraps modal (Google chrome)

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, input

I've ran into a strange problem when playing around with Bootstrap 4 Modals.
When I tried to put a form inside a modal - submitting wouldn't do anything and after inspecting the element in Google Chrome I found out that it shows the input fields are outside the form tags.

My code in question is:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action='test-input.php' method='post' class='ajax-input'>
          <input type='text' name='test-input-field'><input type='submit' name='test-submit'>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But google chrome sees the "modal-body" like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form action='test-input.php' method='post' class='ajax-input'></form>
  <input type='text' name='test-input-field'><input type='submit' name='test-submit'>
</div>
```

Sadly on IE everything works fine. What can be the problem and is there a way to go around this problem if it persists ?

Comment: This seems odd, I wonder if there is another tag somewhere closed too soon or something. Is there page online where I could see this running that might help diagnose the issue?

Comment: IE is notoriously good at mending invalid HTML, but that's not necessarily a good thing. From the sound of it, the code which hits the browser might not be valid HTML. A thorough inspection of the actual page source (`Ctrl+U`) (not the processed HTML(`Ctrl+Shift+I`)) should reveal the problem.

Comment: @JonathanBennett http://www.sidicer.lt/form-problem/ - Click on the "1" button under "Kodas" in the table to summon the modal

Comment: @tao Ctrl+U shows the code correctly while Ctrl+Shift+I show's the form ending before the input fields.

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid direct child of `<tbody>`! Place the modal outside of `<table>` (or in a `<td>`, if you really want to place it inside the `<table>` although it sounds like a bad idea). Ideally you should place it as a direct child of `<body>`. Run your page through the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and ask once you fixed all the errors.

Comment: @tao In use this website generates as many modals as there are "tr's" (rows in mysql) and every "Button" represents a different modal. I'm creating these modals in a while loop after creating tr's with data from my database. Should I be looping another while loop outside the table that generates these modals with the same data?

Comment: No. That's really bad practice. You should only have one empty modal and a function which populates it with the right data once you click on a row button. When closing the modal, remove the contents so it can be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating each modal immediately after the `<tr>`, still inside the `<table>`. This is probably what is causing the issue. You will want to move the modals outside of your table, giving you code something like:

```php
<table>
  <? foreach($item in $items) { %>
   <tr> ... </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>

<? foreach($item in $items) { %>
<div class="modal" id="modal-<?= $item->id ?>">
  ...
</div>
<? } ?>
```